# Excel, automatically updating variable in IF statement based on reference cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet that needs to be *updated monthly* with a formula that needs to change with the month.

This is the formula: `=IF($S3=AI$1,[@July],0)`

The check is to make sure my values go into the correct category. After the category is determined correct, I need to take the month's values by referencing the month column in my table.

**Question:** Is there any way to make it so when I change the month somewhere, I can make the formula essentially move over a column to take the new month's values?

*Note:* I also have a similar case where instead of taking the month values verbatim, I'm summing the year's values til said month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I assume you have a table with column name January to December.

You can do this in at least two ways (I assume your month number is in cell `A1`)

**Explicit:** (in case these columns are not in order or adjacent to another)

```
=CHOOSE(A1,[@January],[@February], ... ,[@December])
```

**Implicit:** (if the months are next to each other:

```
=INDEX(TableName[@[January]:[December]],A1)
```

Obviously, I'd recommend the second option, if applicable.

If you want to sum from januar to the current month, you can use this little know trick/syntax:

```
=SUM([@January]:INDEX(TableName[@[January]:[December]],A1))
```

Comment: okay thanks, i got it to work for the individual months, but how would i incorporate that for the sums?